# Any Yoga routine for Skinny Guys to Gain Muscles?

Tags: exercise, home-exercise, yoga

As I know Yoga can give us many benefits in many ways to our body. I am a skinny guy and I think yoga will also help me to gain muscles. But is there any regular Yoga routine for Skinny Guy Rules to Gaining Muscles?

Comment: There are some aasanas and pranamyams like Kapalbhaati, if done properly, help in weight gain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can help only of you can do [This kinds of exercices](http://cdn-maf2.heartyhosting.com/sites/muscleandfitness.com/files/Yoga.jpg) 
 and that's not even true Yoga.

So to be honest with you, if you think that you're really skinny and you're not hitting bodybuilding at the same time, yoga won't give you the result you're looking for.

Yoga helps you add strength to the small muscles and parts of your body that are normally neglected by other sports. It also helps with flexibility and stress fighting, but flexibility and strength are DEFINITELY NOT mass.

Instead :

- Try to go to a gym near you, try to focus on compound exercies
  instead of isolation ones.
- Favor good form over heavy weight.

If you are unable (for one of the reasons) to go to a gym, then you may look over on youtube for some body weight exercices that can be performed at home for mass building, it normally favors push-ups, squats, burpees and pull-ups (a bar may be necessary).

And I almost forgot, focus also on your DIET, which is a HUGE factor in bulking and adding mass to your body. Try to do a search on food and diets that can suit your reach and of course your pocket ;)

Hope this helps you, have a good day and good luck.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, yoga never ment to be about body physique. As stated in yoga "bible" - "Yoga Sutras of Patanjali",

> yoga is restraining the mind-stuff (Chitta) from taking various forms
> (Vrittis)[1](https://archive.org/stream/RajaYogaAndPatanjalisYogaAphorisms/Raja%20Yoga#page/n51/mode/2up)

which is explained as

> yoga essentially consists of meditative practices culminating in
> attaining a state of consciousness free from all modes of active or
> discursive thought, and of eventually attaining a state where
> consciousness is unaware of any object external to itself, that is, is
> only aware of its own nature as consciousness unmixed with any other
> object [2](http://www.iep.utm.edu/yoga/)

One can quite easily say that yoga is a form of religion or a philosophical school. Asanas or body postures are just instruments to attain required state of mind, just like prayers in Christianity or meditation in buddhism. Asanas were invented as a form of distraction for the mind, so it can let go of thinking process concentrating first on holding asana and then concentrating on itself.

With that in mind, if one to examine yoga from physical prospective, it is more about endurance and flexibility and some strength.

> After analyzing the data, researchers found that the regular practice
> of Hatha yoga significantly improved the subjects’ flexibility,
> muscular strength and endurance, and balance.
>
> [American Council on Exercise: "Does Yoga Really Do the Body Good?"](https://www.acefitness.org/getfit/studies/YogaStudy2005.pdf)
>
> [American Osteopathic Association](http://www.osteopathic.org/osteopathic-health/about-your-health/health-conditions-library/general-health/Pages/yoga.aspx)

In order to grow muscle in size you have to basically damage them so they can repair themselves and when they do, they become bigger to be able to withstand the stress next time and not be damaged. In order to achieve visible growth in size you have to progressively increase the stress your muscles endure, which can only be achieved by so called "progressive overloading" i.e. gradually increasing the amount of weight your muscles have to work with.

In yoga, which is a body weight exercise (again, just from physical prospective), it is impossible to progressively overload. You can extend the amount of time you're exposed to stress, but in this case you'll be targeting muscle endurance, not size.

It needs to be mentioned, that if you're an absolute novice then ANY physical activity will result in muscle "toning" and muscles will appear bigger due to slight growth and reduction in body fat. But in order to achieve any significant gains in size, you have to start using heavy weights.

So, to sum it up:

> Resistance training leads to trauma or injury of the cellular proteins
> in muscle. This prompts cell-signaling messages to activate satellite
> cells to begin a cascade of events leading to muscle repair and
> growth... The most adaptable tissue in the human body is skeletal
> muscle, and it is remarkably remodeled after continuous, and carefully
> designed, resistance exercise training programs. [5](https://www.unm.edu/%7Elkravitz/Article%20folder/musclesgrowLK.html)

Answer (score 0):

Practicing yoga is great for the body and mind, and yes, gaining muscle can be a nice perk. There are so many different types of yoga and practices, and you may have to experiment with a few to find one that suits your needs.

If you're interested in browsing around and trying a few different 'styles' of yoga, I would recommend either going to a yoga studio close to you, or checking out [YogaGlo](https://www.yogaglo.com/). It's a great website with lots of tutorial videos, different styles and classes of varied length. Most styles of yoga will help you gain muscle. Avoid a regular Yin practice as that is intense stretching (might be nice once a week on your 'off day'). Vinyasa-style classes are your best option for gaining muscle. You'll also build it in Hatha, but tends to be a less rigorous practice.

If you're interested in hot yoga, try finding a Moksha/ Modo studio, or a Bikram studio. These are set sequences, and can be as intense as you choose to make them (effort-wise), just keep in mind that if you fall in love with a hot yoga practice, make sure to up your calorie intake. The heat helps to loosen the muscle and get into poses and build lean muscle.

Alternatively, an intense, muscle-building practice would be Ashtanga. It is not done in a hot room, but with the intense breath work, you can work up a good sweat. This is a great practice to do at home, but I would **strongly** recommend going to a studio and practicing under the guidance of a teacher first (that goes for any style of yoga you choose).

Keep in mind that with yoga "no pain, no gain" does not exist. If it feels bad in your body, DON'T do it. With building muscle and practice, it is a process.